# Restrict visibility of a transaction between 2 parties decided on runtime

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Assume we have 100+ organizations in Hyperledger fabric network. One Org can choose another Org randomly and perform a transaction.
The transaction includes sensitive information that should be only accessible by the 2 Orgs involved in the transaction.
How can we achieve this functionality, hide the transaction details from other Orgs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use private data collection (PDC) for permitted orgs in transaction. In this case all other orgs will have the hash only.